# Realm db ChangeListener persistence - memory leak

Tags: android, listener, realm

I'm taking an Android class where the app uses a Realm db and a ChangeListener is added to the asynchronous query result.  The documentation indicates the listener should be added in onStart and removed in onStop so that memory is not leaked if the instance is destroyed.  The db configuration and default instance are declared in a class which extends Application - so the default Realm db instance will persist, but will the query results?  And if the query result does not persist, why the need to remove the listener from the result whereas with an onClickListener (for instance), that listener does not need to be removed?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know internals of Realm, but let's use deduction =)

Application is a singleton (the one instance of the object, that will live as long as your application).

Realm db instance as member will live with Application object.

A caller, for example Activity, subscribes to the results (observer pattern - "hey, ping me when there is smth for me"). When the Activity adds himself as listener it gives its reference. So garbage collector cannot reap Activity after configuration change (ex. device rotation).

onStop - is a callback that indicates possible destruction of the Activity, so it has to unsubscribe ("don't hold me").

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If you add a `RealmChangeListener` to a `RealmResults`, the listener will be GCed after Realm detects the `RealmResults` is GCed -- Realm is hold a weak reference to the `RealmResults` and check the weak ref at some point. If the `RealmChangeListener` is added to a `Realm`, it will be removed if the Realm instance gets closed or calling `removeChangeListener`/`removeAllChangeListeners`. In this case if you holding the Realm instance in the application life cycle and don't remove the listeners manually, it will be leaked.

In general, it would be a good practice to remove them if they are not needed anymore to avoid wasting cpu/mem resources.

Comment: could you define GCed, please?

Comment: Garbage collected.  Please disregard previous question.